# JNA Pointer to Pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to use JNA and execute with a pointer to a pointer but I keep having trouble.  I am able to use other functions in the class, however the arguments in this function are giving me trouble.  My interface and java where works fine, and i can use the other methods, however "execute_file" & "alenkaexecute" is giving me trouble.  Is my method declaration off?  I am thinking maybe i should have a string array instead of PointerByReference?  At the bottom i included the c++ with execute_file.

Thank you!

```
public interface libcvm extends Library{
        void alenkaInit(PointerByReference av);
        int execute_file(int ac, PointerByReference av);
        void alenkaClose();
        int alenkaExecute(ByteBuffer s); 
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        libcvm libcvm = (libcvm) Native.loadLibrary("libcvm.so", libcvm.class);
        PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
        libcvm.execute_file(2, pref);
        Pointer p = pref.getValue();    
    }


int execute_file(int ac, char **av)
{
bool just_once = 0;
string script;

    process_count = 6200000;
    verbose = 0;
total_buffer_size = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < ac; i++) {
        if(strcmp(av[i],"-l") == 0) {
            process_count = atoff(av[i+1]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(av[i],"-v") == 0) {
            verbose = 1;
        }
        else if(strcmp(av[i],"-i") == 0) {
            interactive = 1;
break;
        }
        else if(strcmp(av[i],"-s") == 0) {
            just_once = 1;
interactive = 1;
script = av[i+1];
        };  
    };

load_col_data(data_dict, "data.dictionary");

    if (!interactive) {
        if((yyin = fopen(av[ac-1], "r")) == NULL) {
            perror(av[ac-1]);
            exit(1);
        };

        if(yyparse()) {
            printf("SQL scan parse failed\n");
            exit(1);
        };

//exit(0);

        scan_state = 1;
        std::clock_t start1 = std::clock();

load_vars();

        statement_count = 0;
        clean_queues();

        yyin = fopen(av[ac-1], "r");
        PROC_FLUSH_BUF ( yyin );
        statement_count = 0;

        extern FILE *yyin;
        context = CreateCudaDevice(0, av, verbose);
        hash_seed = 100;

        if(!yyparse()) {
            if(verbose)
            cout << "SQL scan parse worked " << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "SQL scan parse failed" << endl;

        fclose(yyin);
        for (map<string,CudaSet*>::iterator it=varNames.begin() ; it != varNames.end(); ++it ) {
            (*it).second->free();
        };

        if(alloced_sz) {
            cudaFree(alloced_tmp);
        };

        if(verbose) {
            cout<< "cycle time " << ( ( std::clock() - start1 ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) << " " << getFreeMem() << endl;
        };
    }
    else {
        context = CreateCudaDevice(0, av, verbose);
        hash_seed = 100;
if(!just_once)
getline(cin, script);   

        while (script != "exit" && script != "EXIT") {

used_vars.clear();
            yy_scan_string(script.c_str());
            scan_state = 0;
            statement_count = 0;
            clean_queues();
            if(yyparse()) {
                printf("SQL scan parse failed \n");
                getline(cin, script);
                continue;
            };

            scan_state = 1;

load_vars();

            statement_count = 0;
            clean_queues();
            yy_scan_string(script.c_str());
            std::clock_t start1 = std::clock();

            if(!yyparse()) {
                if(verbose)
                    cout << "SQL scan parse worked " << endl;
            };
            for (map<string,CudaSet*>::iterator it=varNames.begin() ; it != varNames.end(); ++it ) {
                (*it).second->free();
            };
            varNames.clear();

            if(verbose) {
                cout<< "cycle time " << ( ( std::clock() - start1 ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) << endl;
            };
if(!just_once)
getline(cin, script);
else
script = "exit";
        };
        if(alloced_sz) {
            cudaFree(alloced_tmp);
            alloced_sz = 0;
        };

while(!buffer_names.empty()) {
delete [] buffers[buffer_names.front()];
buffer_sizes.erase(buffer_names.front());
buffers.erase(buffer_names.front());
buffer_names.pop();
};

    };
if(save_dict)
save_col_data(data_dict,"data.dictionary");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your API is asking for `char**`, which in common C parlance is an array of strings.

JNA will handle the conversion automatically if you use `String[]` as the argument type.